# How to display data from database into bar chart on Laravel 8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, charts

This is my first time creating and using a bar chart and I'm trying to display data about users from my database in a bar chart. So, I watched and copied a tutorial but nothing is being displayed on my page, even one word. I still don't understand how this works, does it display elements even if it is unable to retrieve data from the database? below is my database table.

| id | name | email | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | John@gmail.com | 2022-09-02 05:35:56 | 2022-09-02 05:35:56 |
| 2 | Mike | Mike@gmail.com | 2022-09-02 06:14:10 | 2022-09-02 06:14:10 |
| 3 | Mikael | Mikael@gmail.com | 2022-10-03 11:35:56 | 2022-09-02 11:35:56 |
| 4 | Will | Will@gmail.com | 2022-10-06 01:14:10 | 2022-09-02 01:14:10 |

My route:

```
Route::get("/bar-chart",[HomeController::class,"barChart"]);
```

My controller:

```
public function barChart(){
    $users=user::select(user::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
            ->whereYear('created_at',date('Y'))
            ->groupBy(user::raw("Month(created_at)"))
            ->pluck('count');
    $months=user::select(user::raw("COUNT(*) as month"))
            ->whereYear('created_at',date('Y'))
            ->groupBy(user::raw("Month(created_at)"))
            ->pluck('month');
    $datas = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); 
    foreach($months as $index =>$month){
        $datas[$month] = $users[$index];
    }       
    return view('bar-chart', compact('datas'));
}
```

And my blade file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample Chart</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb60SsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha512-vBmx0N/uQOXznm/Nbkp7h0P1RfLSj0HQrFSzV8m7rOGyj30fYAOKHYvCNez+yM8IrfnW0TCodDEjRqf6fodf/Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:400px; width:900px; margin-auto;">
        <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function()){
            var datas = <?php echo json_encode($datas); ?>
            var barCanvas = $("#barChart");
            var barChart = new Chart(barCanvas,{
                type:'bar'
                data:{
                    labels:['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
                    datasets:[{
                        label:'Users, 2022',
                        data:datas,
                        backgroundColor:['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet','purple','pink','silver','gold','brown']
                    }]
                },
                options:{
                    scales:{
                        yAxes:[{
                            ticks:{
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should it be ```User::``` instead of ```user::```

Comment: Every time I use my database, all the letters are small letters, and always works tho. I also tried that but the result is still the same, unfortunately.